# MVC4 WebSecurity - how do I modify the cookie data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, membership

MVC4 seems to have a new membership database using tables generated automatically by EF code first.

I am attempting to migrate my MVC3 application to this new membership database.
**What I can't figure out is how I change the USER DATA in the cookie when using WebSecurity.**  I use this to provide additional permission data so that my application can provide more granular access without having to hit the database all the time and in addition work with the cookie not against it.

In MVC3 I used FormsAuthentication where I set the FormsAuthentication cookie with custom data.
**Below is a sample of what I would like to achieve in MVC4 using WebSecurity. How?**

```
// Get the access details from the database so we can place it into the cookie
TicketUserData tud = new AuthorizationTicketData().BuildTicketUserDataFromDatabase(userName);

// Create the auth cookie
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                                                    1,
                                                    userName,
                                                    System.DateTime.Now,
                                                    System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                                                    false,
                                                    tud.ToString(),
                                                    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

// Encrypt the ticket to protect the data (this will look at the web.config forms settings)
string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

// Create the cookie
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Also, how to get the user data once set - since it's not FormsAuthentication - (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Ticket would this still be valid?

Comment: I have been programming using "Simple" Membership with an ef code first back end (so been busy) - will come back to this in a few weeks.